# I don't understand what is wrong with this sentence. Can anyone help?

Tags: modal-verbs, could

The sentence is:

> The bank manager was told not to hold him back, so this man *could*
>   escape

It is illustrated in a book as containing an error. The writer reports how judges responded to it and writes:

> The problem with it for many judges was the past tense form *could*,
>   which was ungrammatical with the one-off meaning while being good with
>   the 'habitually in the past' meaning. It would also be unobjectionable
>   if negative: *couldn't* is fine with the semelfactive meaning"

My problem is I don't see what is wrong with *could* and what is right with *couldn't*. Does anyone know?

Comment: I'd certainly substitute 'was able to'; using 'could' is at best ambiguous.

Comment: ambiguous in what way? @EdwinAshworth

Comment: "The bank manager was told not to hold him back, so as to allow this man to escape".  // "The bank manager was told not to hold him back, so it is possible that this man could escape". Modals are famously polysemous, and so is 'so'.

Comment: thumbs-up@EdwinAshworth

Answer (score 1):

I'm with you.  I see nothing wrong with the sentence if said with the intonation indicated with the comma. Then the sentence structure is as indicated here:

> [The bank manager was told not to hold him back,] [so this man could escape].

the last clause is an inference we are to make.  Because of what the bank manager was told, the man was able to escape.

Without the comma, however, the last clause could be in the scope of the preceding "not":

> [The bank manager was told not [to hold him back so this man could escape] ]

which does not make much sense, since it means the bank manager told that he should not hold him in a fashion that would let him escape.  But that would be not holding him at all.

However, it would make sense to say

> The bank manager was told not to hold him back so this man couldn't escape.

which would mean the bank manager was told that he could hold the man back, but only in a fashion which would let the man escape.

Maybe it's confusion with this last sense that has the judges confused.

Answer (score 0):

*The bank manager was told not to hold him back, so this man **could** escape.*

I read this without reading the question and saw no problems.  I then saw that it contained an error!  I can only say that to my British English ears the '**could**' here is clearly meaning '**would be able to**'.

If the sentence is inverted, interestingly, **couldn't** would NOT work for me precisely because it sounds 'habitual-in-the-past' (not the desired sense).  So, in this case, I would say

*The bank manager was told to hold him back, so this man would not be able to escape.*

Comment: I am lost now@Dan

Comment: The sense of 'could' in the OP is 'would be able to (at that moment)'.  This sense is conveyed to me unambiguously by either version.  The curious problem I'm struggling to explain is that when the sentence is inverted the 'habitually-in-the-past' sense of couldn't is more powerful than the 'at-that-moment' sense and this creates a confusing clash with the simple past tense  in the first half of the phrase describing an actual incident.